# Jquery toggleclass won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `toggleclass` function won't work, and I have no clue why. Any help is appreciated thanks!

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t763P/1460/

```
<li id="toggle-favicon">
    <a href="#">Orders <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
            <a href="#">File orders</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Product orders</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

$('#toggle-favicon').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('fa-chevron-left fa-chevron-down');
    console.log($(this).find('span'));
});
```

Comment: because your span has been commented out by something and replaced with an svg

Comment: FontAwesome 5 is causing this issue, it replaces your `span` with an `svg`. There are some options to avoid that in their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In latest version of font awesome, `<span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>` will get converted to some SVG Element. And the corresponding span element is removed.

Hence, to change the class of the icon, you will need to toggle the class of this svg element.

Also keep in mind that `.toggleClass` wont work on `svg` elements as `jQuery v1.x` can not do that. So you will need to use `.attr("class" ... )` method.

```
$('#toggle-favicon').click(function() {
  var $el = $(this).find('svg');
  $el.attr("class", function() {
    return $(this).attr("class").indexOf("fa-chevron-left") != -1 ? "fa-chevron-right" : "fa-chevron-left";
  })
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t763P/1472/)**

If you use `jQuery 3.x` then you can use `.toggleClass` as well...

```
$('#toggle-favicon').click(function() {
  var $el = $(this).find('svg');
  $el.toggleClass("fa-chevron-left fa-chevron-right");
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t763P/1478/)**